# VBA xlBarClustered how do you distinguish between the two different presets?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I have a chart template saved using the xlBarclustered chart type. I want it to be based upon the left default chart (see image below) but it chooses right. I have another document with a copy of the same code that chooses right. Is it possible to distinguish?
[image]
When using record macro it has the same code for both left and right charts which is copied below.

Thanks

```
Set cht = WS_FS.Shapes.AddChart2(216, xlBarClustered, Left:=WS_FS.Cells(row, 5).Left, Top:=WS_FS.Cells(row, 5).Top, Width:=425, Height:=250)
cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change how the data is plotted:

```
cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng PlotBy:=xlColumns
```

To get the left hand chart:

```
cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng PlotBy:=xlRows
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help!

To confirm the left hand chart is: PlotBy:=xlColumns