# How to set xlColumnClustered style with only one color and values below each bar?

Tags: excel, vba

I create VBA Column Clustered charts and there are two styles of xlColumnClustered:

- with multiple colors
- with one color and values below each bar

It displays the first one and I need the second one:

[image: Column clustered]

In VBA how do I set xlColumnClustered to have one  color with values below each bar?

Here is my code:

```
Sub CreateGraph()

Dim strChrt As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim x As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim lastCol As Integer
Dim myShape As Shape

Set ws = ActiveSheet
lastCol = ws.Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
For x = 4 To lastRow

  With ws
    Set range1 = .Range(.Cells(3, "A"), .Cells(3, lastCol))
    Set range2 = .Range(.Cells(x, "A"), .Cells(x, lastCol))
    Set range3 = Union(range1, range2)
    Set myShape = .Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered) 
  End With

  With myShape.Chart
    .SetSourceData Source:=range3
    .ChartTitle.Text = ws.Cells(x, "A")
    .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    .HasLegend = False     
  End With

  With myShape.Chart.Axes(xlValue)
    .HasTitle = True
    .AxisTitle.Caption = "Frequency"
  End With

  With myShape.Chart.Axes(xlCategory)
    .HasTitle = True
    .AxisTitle.Caption = "Time"
  End With
Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: I added a pictue and the VBA code ;-)

Comment: Untested, but try changing `Set myShape = .Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered)` to `Set myShape = .Shapes.AddChart2(-1, xlColumnClustered)`

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work better.

Comment: I have used a template from the chart I want and I have applied with: myShape.Chart.ApplyChartTemplate ( _ "C:\..........\Charts\ChartTpl.crtx") but it does not work, I have sometimes the ColumnClustered with multiple colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a similar question on [xlBarClustered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53672735/vba-xlbarclustered-how-do-you-distinguish-between-the-two-different-presets), you need to change how the data is plotted:

To get the left hand chart:

```
myShape.Chart.PlotBy = xlColumns
```

To get the right hand chart:

```
myShape.Chart.PlotBy = xlRows
```